# Enable/Disable Button working only after page Refresh

Tags: angular

I wanted to enable button if the `mode` is `edit` else if the `mode` is `view` i should disable it.

I get the mode value from Service.

problem is if the mode is changed to edit, button is not getting enabled. It is only getting enabled after i refresh the page. Please help

```js
// service.ts
getMode() {
  if (this.endSessionBtnActive)
    this.mode = 'edit';
  else
    this.mode = 'view';

  return this.mode;
}

//comporent.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.mode = this.sessionWatch.getMode().valueOf();
  alert(this.mode);
  if (this.mode == 'edit') {
    this.showCreateProposalsBtn = true;
  } else {
    this.showCreateProposalsBtn = false
    alert('hidden');
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="icon-links" *ngIf="showCreateProposalsBtn === true">
  <i *ngIf="showMyProposals&&selectedStatus[0]==='01'&&isAlertModal===false" class="npt-icon-add icon-states" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="checkUnassigned()"></i>

</a>
<a class="icon-links" *ngIf="showCreateProposalsBtn === false">
  <i class="npt-icon-add icon-states-disabled" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear : you speak about a button and there's none ; in your code there are variables we don't know because you reduced your code before posting it ; etc. Please post your whole code and explain how we should see it.

Comment: Yeah it's weird *ngIf will get bugged I would suggest using `[hidden]` I had the same issue and never found a solution for it. Just switch true and false around, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change in the mode then you need to subscribe to the change.

Add the following code to you service

```
 currentMode$ = this.currentActiveMode.asObservable();  

  changeCurrentMode (currentStep: string) {
    this.currentActiveMode.next(currentStep);
  }
```

modify your get mode function as to add following

```
getMode() {
  if (this.endSessionBtnActive)
    this.changeCurrentMode('edit');
  else
    this.changeCurrentMode('view');
}
```

With that in place now you can subscribe the mode form anywhere in you project.

Add the following code in you components constructor

```
sessionWatch.currentMode$.subscribe(
  mode => {
    this.mode = mode;
  }
);
```

Comment: I'm trying you're method, but i'm getting an error `[ts] Property 'currentActiveMode' does not exist on type 'SessionWatchService'.
`

Comment: private currentActiveMode             = new Subject<string>();
add this to your service declarations.

Comment: But i still getting some error ` Property 'currentMode$' does not exist on type 'SessionWatchService'.` in component.ts

Comment: can u share your code in plunker? Atleast the working of your code what you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
//comporent.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.mode = this.sessionWatch.getMode().valueOf();
  alert(this.mode);
}

<a class="icon-links" *ngIf="mode == 'edit'">
  <i *ngIf="showMyProposals&&selectedStatus[0]==='01'&&isAlertModal===false" class="npt-icon-add icon-states" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="checkUnassigned()"></i>

</a>
<a class="icon-links" *ngIf="mode == 'view'">
  <i class="npt-icon-add icon-states-disabled" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your value is only updated once, on Init.

```
//template
<a class="icon-links" *ngIf="shouldShowCreateProposalsBtn()">


//component.ts
shouldShowCreateProposalsBtn()
{
  this.mode = this.sessionWatch.getMode().valueOf();
  return this.mode == 'edit';
}
```

Comment: I would not suggest this approach. This method in template will be called on each change detection.

Comment: @AJT_82: what would you propose then?

Comment: Gautam presented a viable solution. Also it could be done without Observables :)